# Matrix powers and recurrence relations

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

The nth Fibonacci number can be found by raising the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ to the nth power. Are there other recurrence formulas that can be solved like this? This yields faster algorithms for computing them.

Comment: Yes, any constant coefficients linear homogeneous recurrent relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - all *constant coefficient homogeneous linear* recurrence relations can be solved this way:
Let $a_n=\alpha_{1}a_{n-1}+...+\alpha_{r}a_{n-r}$ be a recurrence relation with initial conditions - given $a_0,...,a_{r-1}$. Then, observing that
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\a_{n-1}\\a_{n-2}\\\vdots\\a_{n-r+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\alpha_3&... &\alpha_{r-1}&\alpha_r\\
1&0&0&...&0&0\\
0&1&0&...&0&0\\
\vdots& &\ddots& &&\vdots\\
0&0&0&...&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a_{n-1}\\a_{n-2}\\a_{n-3}\\\vdots\\a_{n-r}\end{pmatrix}$$
Denote that matrix by $A$. Then we see that 
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\a_{n-1}\\a_{n-2}\\\vdots\\a_{n-r+1}\end{pmatrix}=A^{n-r}
\begin{pmatrix}a_{r-1}\\a_{r-2}\\a_{r-3}\\\vdots\\a_{0}\end{pmatrix}$$
So you need to raise $A$ to the $n$th power to find $a_n$.

Comment: Do I use induction to prove this result?

Comment: Yes, you should - if you want a formal proof.