# Fibonacci matrix for different constant values in recurrence relation

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

For Fibonacci series we have a recurrence relation $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.So the initial matrix can be written as $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1\\
1 &0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $a_{11}=F_{n+1}, a_{21}$ and $a_{12}$ are $F_n$ and $a_{22}=F_{n-1}$
We can calculate $n$th Fibonacci by raising this matrix to the power of $n$.

What if the recurrence relation is $F_n=F_{n-1}+4F_{n-2}$ What will the matrix be?

I have a fibonacci recurrence relation as the following: 
$$F_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}} \bigg(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n\bigg)$$

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546910/matrix-powers-and-recurrence-relations?rq=1)

Comment: Do you understand how the matrix $A$ relates to the first recurrence?

Answer (score 1):

If $x_{n+2}=ax_{n+1}+bx_n$ just put $[a,b]$ as row $1$ and $[1,0]$ as row $2$ for the update. You'll have to take a power of this times a fixed column vector giving the initial values (first value on top of column vector).

Correction (I think): If first two terms are different, I now think first term goes on bottom of initial value column vector, second term on top. Experiment-- try it both ways to make sure which is right.

Comment: Thank You.It works

Answer (score 0):

These two pictures gives a fair idea on how to create T matric and solve any recurrence relation using matrix exponentiation:

https://ibb.co/k98WdxR

https://ibb.co/9sJLNwX